# Is it any other way to shorten this SQL function especially MOD function?

Tags: sql, optimization, modulus

I have this query

```
SELECT Calendar."Production Week" FROM Opex 
WHERE 
(
Calendar."Production Week" BETWEEN  VALUEOF("LAST_WEEK")-200 
AND  
VALUEOF("LAST_WEEK")
) 
OR 
(
(
(MOD(Calendar."Production Week", 100) = 1) 
OR 
(MOD(Calendar."Production Week", 100) = 13) 
OR 
(MOD(Calendar."Production Week", 100) = 26) 
OR 
(MOD(Calendar."Production Week", 100) = 39) 
OR 
(MOD(Calendar."Production Week", 100) = 52)   
)  
AND 
(Calendar."Production Week" <=
VALUEOF("LAST_WEEK"))
) 
ORDER BY Calendar."Production Week" DESC
```

then my question, is it any other way to make this query more shorter than it especially the MOD function because of it has the same result 200639, 200652, 200713, 2007 26, 200739...etc? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the chain of OR to an IN clause

```
MOD(Calendar."Production Week", 100) in (1,13,26,39,52)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MOD(Calendar."Production Week", 100) IN (1,13,26,39,52)
```

That sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Calendar."Production Week" FROM Opex
WHERE (
     Calendar."Production Week" BETWEEN VALUEOF("LAST_WEEK")-200 AND VALUEOF("LAST_WEEK")
)
OR
(
     (
        (MOD(Calendar."Production Week", 100) in (1, 13, 26, 39, 52)
     )
     AND  (Calendar."Production Week" <= VALUEOF("LAST_WEEK"))
)
ORDER BY Calendar."Production Week" DESC
```